# When and why should I use System.arraycopy (or: arrays vs collections)

Tags: java

In the answers here lately, I found some different habits (or flavours). So I wonder when and why is the use of Java's `System.arraycopy(...)` preferable to something like `Collection.addAll(...)`? When not?

**Edit:** It boils down to arrays vs. collections. Thanks so far. But which can be handled more effeciently by the computer or is... well... better for programmers?

Thanks
Mike
[;-)

Comment: @DerMike: Sorry, we were editing the question at the same time. I have combined both our edits now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for one thing `System.arraycopy(...)` works on arrays, and `Collection.addAll()` on collections - so what you can use depends on what kind of objects you have to work with.

The alternative to `System.arraycopy(...)` with arrays is writing a loop and copying elements manually. This is

- More code
- Thus, more likely to contain an error
- In most cases slower because `System.arraycopy(...)` is a native method that can use fast memory copy routines provided by the OS.

Comment: Using System.arraycopy() allows the OS to do a Copy-On-Write array. If you never change the data in the second array its memeory is never allocated.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not `Collection`s. So whenever you need to copy things from an array to another array, use `System.arraycopy`. If you need to add things from one `Collection` to another `Collection`, use `Collection.add()` or `Collection.addAll()`.

Answer (score 2):

You comparison doesn't make many sense ... Arrays are not Collections. `System.arraycopy` is a  very fast `native` method for copying arrays. That's why people and the Java framework itself use it.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I would recommend the usage of collections in most cases. Especially in interfaces and public methods.

For example if you can choose between:

```
public List<Integer> getFoo();
public int[] getFoo();
```

The first method gives you the opportunity to change the implementation `ArrayList` vs `LinkedList`, etc. Or to return an immutable version via `Collections.unmodifiableList()`.

If you return an array in an interface method you might be forced to make a defensive copy before returning it, since you cannot prevent the client from changing the array content. Furthermore lists have only few disadvantages compared to arrays, you can almost always replace an array with an `ArrayList` for example.

Place where arrays still make sense would be varargs methods, or algorithmic code, where the speed benefit of operations like `clone` and `System.arraycopy` are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Array are not collection. that's why we are using Sysytem.arrcopy its native method for copying array but it is very fast